# Separating lower case and uppercase with a comma in Pandas Series

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace, series

I have a pandas series

```
list_df = pd.Series(['KingsDuck',
       'RangersIslandersDevils',
       'Shark',
       'Maple Leafs',
       'Red Wing'])

display(list_df)
0                 KingsDuck
1    RangersIslandersDevils
2                     Shark
3               Maple Leafs
4                  Red Wing
dtype: object
```

and I would like to insert a comma between lower character and upper character. (Eg: 'KingsDuck' to 'Kings,Duck' and 'RangersIslandersDevils' to 'Rangers,Islanders,Devils')

I tried an online python regex tools to test my regex and it worked as intended:
[regextesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyCyc.png)

However when I tried the regex in my Jupyter Notebook, the output is not what I expected:

```
list_df.replace(r'(([a-z])([A-Z]))',r'\1,\2', regex=True)
0                   KingsD,suck
1    RangersI,sslandersD,sevils
2                         Shark
3                   Maple Leafs
4                      Red Wing
dtype: object
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many groups, remove the external parentheses. You have `((a)(b))` so `\1` is `ab`, `\2` is `a`, `\3` is `b`.

```
list_df.replace(r'([a-z])([A-Z])',
                r'\1,\2', regex=True)
```

Or if you really want to keep the external group:

```
list_df.replace(r'(([a-z])([A-Z]))',
                r'\2,\3', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0                  Kings,Duck
1    Rangers,Islanders,Devils
2                       Shark
3                 Maple Leafs
4                    Red Wing
dtype: object
```

Comment: Alternatively - it's also doable using a look behind: `list_df.replace(r'(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])', r',\1', regex=True)` (which seems to be a little more explicit to me as to the intent).

Comment: @Jon in this case you can even bypass all references: `list_df.replace(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', r',', regex=True)` ;)